# TypeError: Cannot read property '_pool' of undefined

Tags: mysql, database, express

I'm trying to release the query after executing it successfully to prevent the query to stay in the pool but faced an error of

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_pool' of undefined
>   .

```
router.get('/articles', (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES";
  myDB.query(sql, (error, results) => {
    myDB.releaseConnection();
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      res.send(results)
    }
  })
});
```

and this is my connection

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const myDB = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'server.address.here',
    user: 'hmidev',
    password: 'hmidev',
    database: 'VD_NEW_WEBSITE'
});

myDB.getConnection((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(`Successfully connected at VD_NEW_WEBSITE`);
    }
});

module.exports = myDB;
```

This is what my database looks like:

[image: db image]

**EDIT:** Added image

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on the localhost ?
If you are Working on the localhost ,
you need to change your host to localhost